# multiple routing files (refresh page)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have multiple routing files, and all works fine.
The problem is when I get a list of companies `url/companies` and I select a company `url/companies/:id` it leads to company page(that's good). But when I refresh the company page it's not working.

The app routing file: `app.routing.ts`

```
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        data: {
            title: 'login'
        },
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: FullLayoutComponent,
        data: {
            title: 'Home'
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                loadChildren: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'companies',
                loadChildren: 'app/companies/companies.module#CompaniesModule'
            },
    }
```

the companies routing file: `companies.routing.ts`

```
{
    path: '',
    data: {
        title: 'Companies'
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: CompaniesComponent,
        },
        {
            path: ':company',
            component: CompanyComponent,
            data: {
                title: 'Company'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '**',
            component: CompaniesComponent,
            data: {
                title: 'Company'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Another thing, the '**' in the `companies.routing.ts` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

In my `index.html` I have `<base href="./">`.
When I reload my page, CSS file change the directory to the company instead root directory, could not get the CSS file.

Right path : `127.0.0.1:4200/myfile.css`

Actual path : `127.0.0.1:4200/companies/myfile.css`

I changed the base href in my `index.html` by `<base href="/">`